# When updating a mongodb document, what is the most efficient way to determine the modified fields?

Tags: php, mongodb

When updating a document, I'd like to return the fields that were modified during the update and, if possible, the previous values.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`findAndModify`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) command to support that use case.